# SQL Server error with ' ' insert into table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
INSERT INTO Article (CatID, Title, Content) 
VALUES ('100', 'New color, new choice', '<span style="font-family:'Times New Roman'">etc...etc</span>')
```

I try to insert data into a table in SQL Server with this command, but I get an error:

> Incorrect syntax near 'Times'

What is wrong here, and how can I fix it?

Comment: You have unescaped single quotes in the third column

Comment: Use a double single quote (not a double quote) to escape your single quotes in the text values.

Comment: @JacobH Ah, that right, i forgot about it, thank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Around the **Times New Roman** in the `Content` value, you need to add `'` to escape the single quotes:

```
INSERT INTO Article (
    CatID
    ,Title
    ,Content
    )
VALUES (
    '100'
    ,'New color, new choice'
    ,'<span style="font-family:''Times New Roman''">etc...etc</span>'
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape single quote, using two single quotes:

```
Insert into Article(CatID, Title, Content) values ('100','New color, new 
choice','<span style="font-family:''Times New Roman''">etc...etc</span>')
```

Right after and before Times New Roman there are two `'` characters instead of one, otherwise the interpreter will think the string ends with `...family:`

Answer (score 1):

You have unescaped single quotes in the third column. Use a double single quote (`''`) to escape that:

```
INSERT INTO Article
(CatID, Title, Content) 
VALUES
('100', 'New color, new choice', '<span style="font-family:''Times New Roman''">etc...etc</span>')
                                                     --    ^^ This and this ^^
```